# Split screen plugin for gedit 3.10.4

Tags: python, gedit, plugins

I would like to split the screen in gedit in order to see simultaneously multiple files.

I found this plugin

https://github.com/jonocodes/GeditSplitView

but after moving

*SplitView.plugin*

*SplitView.py*

to .local/share/gedit/plugins

and going to edit->preferences->plugins
if I try to click on the split view button a no entry sign appears.
" 'python' plugin loader was not found"

If I run gedit from the terminal, I receive the following message:

(gedit:17504): libpeas-WARNING **: The 'python' plugin loader has not been enabled

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5):

I think newer Gedit versions work with Python 3 instead of 2. So you might want to change the loader in `SplitView.plugin`.

Change line 2 from

```
Loader=python
```

to

```
Loader=python3
```